# Data from last 13 months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've a table in SQL Server 2008 database which has a column 'Month', nvarchar datatype, where the data is stored in the format 'Jan 2013', 'Feb 2013', 'Mar 2013' and so on till 'Mar 2014'.

Now I want the data from Mar 2013 to Mar 2014 in my result but am not able to get that.

Am trying this where clause : **WHERE (Month > DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(year, 0, GETDATE()) - 13, 0))** but it's giving me an error saying **Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**

I've also tried renaming the data as 'March 2014' and subsuquently for other entries as well, but it's not helping either.

Dear SQL experts, please help!

Comment: _"column 'Month', nvarchar datatype, where the data is stored in the format 'Jan 2013"_ Why don't you store it as `datetime` or `date` in the first place? That's cheaper, less error-prone and allows to use date functions. You should convert it to a string where you display it, so at the very last place. That has also the advantage that you can show the month in different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
where (LEFT(month,3) not in ('jan','feb') and right(month,4)='2013')
OR (LEFT(month,3) in ('jan','feb') and right(month,4)='2014')
```

The resultset will include March 2013 but not March 2014 if you want to include march 2014 change the last part of the where clause to `(LEFT(month,3) in ('jan','feb','mar') and right(month,4)='2014')`
But I recommend that you store your dates as datetime

Comment: Thanks Hedinn! :)

It solved my pupose for now. But let's say if I want to make it a rolling 13 months then?

For e.g. : Next month I'll be needing the data from Apr 2013 to Apr 2014; do I need to manually add / remove the contents every other month? Please advise.

On a separate note, I've raised the request for changing the design and datatype of 'Month' field to datetime.

Comment: for a rolling 13 months I would use something like Gordon Linoff recommends in other answer to this question so use the where clause, ´where convert(date, '01 ' + [Month]) > DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()) - 13, 0)´

Comment: `where convert(date, '01 ' + [Month]) > DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()) - 13, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Yucky format for date.  My advice is to convert it to an actual date.  Happily, SQL Server recognizes the following format:

```
select convert(date, '15 MAR 2014')
```

So, you can do:

```
where convert(date, '15 ' + [Month]) > DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(year, 0, GETDATE()) - 13, 0)
```

I arbitrarily set the date to the middle of the month.  You might want to use `'01'` rather than `'15'`.